# Why actual host ip is removed from iptables rule

Tags: networking, iptables

I added this rule in iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.100/24 -p tcp --dport 27 -j ACCEPT
```

To my surprise, when I list the iptables rules, i see this:
source value became

```
192.168.0.0/24
```

Why?

Comment: `192.168.0.100/24` and `192.168.0.0/24` represent the same set of addresses

Comment: Though slightly confusing but makes sense. Can you please point me to documentation where you saw that iptables assumes them to be same set of address. As according to my understanding it should consider them differently.

Comment: It is  neither about iptables nor Unix, it is about having networking basic concepts. 192.168.0.100/32 is 192.168.0.100, 192.168.0.100/24 maps to 192.168.0.0; it is /number_of bits

Comment: @derobert Please do feel free to answer, busy at work atm.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro done, I hope it makes sense to OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`192.168.0.100/24` can be a **shorthand** for 192.168.100/255.255.255.0 - configuring a device with the IP address 192.168.0.100 and the netmask 255.255.255.0. That's probably what you're expecting; but that's not how iptables is using it. If you just want to accept that particular host, and not the entire network, leave off the mask (or use `/32`, which is the same thing).

Strictly speaking, according to the manpage, it could spit out an error:

> ```
>   [!] -s, --source address[/mask][,...]
>           Source specification. Address can be either a network name, a hostname, a  network
>           IP  address  (with  /mask), or a plain IP address. Hostnames will be resolved once
>           ⋮
> ```

A mask can only go with a "network IP address", and 192.168.0.100 is not one (for a /24 network). The network address is what it's giving back to you — 192.168.0.0/24.

That raises the question: *what is a network IP address?*

A device/computer needs to know if another address is on the same network (and thus it can communicate directly) or if its on a different network (thus it needs to go through the gateway). The way this works is that a range of IP addresses are considered on the same network based on the network address, the netmask and some binary arithmetic. To find the network a given IP address is on you do a binary-and against the netmask (you line up the two addresses in binary and if both are 1, you write down a 1; otherwise, 0). Since netmasks always a bunch of 1s followed by some 0s, we abbreviate them by counting the number of 1s. A /24 means 24 1s and 8 0s (IPv4 is 32 bits long).

```
  (192)    (168)    (0)      (100)
  11000000 10101000 00000000 01100100
& 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
= 11000000 10101000 00000000 00000000  = 192.168.0.0
```

And you'll notice that if you try this with 192.168.0.1–255, they all come to the same answer: that is why they are considered on the same network.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation. @ derobert  Bottomline iptables does not honour subnet mask /24 correct?

Comment: @pzk the point of the answer is that there is  nothing to honour

Comment: Took the liberty to make a small edit for the benefit of the OP, if you do not mind.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thank you, don't mind at all

Comment: @pzk `-s` can match against a single host/IP address (if you do not give a mask) or it can match against a network (if you give the network address and a mask, e.g., `/24`). You gave it a non-network address and a mask — it "helpfully" converted it to the network address for you, instead of returning an error (or even worse, silently *never* matching, because that isn't a network address)